# How do I access values from .env in Laravel 5.1 TestCase

Tags: testing, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.1 TestCase, the baseUrl is hard-coded. I'd like to set it based on the value I have set in .env.

How do I access the .env variables within the TestCase class?

Comment: `env('APP_ENV')` doesn't work?

Comment: No it simply returns NULL for values that are assigned in my .env file. I believe it's because it's looking to phpunit.xml for ENV vars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 5.2 I replaced the Dotenv::load call with this ...

```
$app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
```

Answer (score 5):

in Laravel 5.0 `TestCase`, I can get .env variable with following function.

```
getenv('APP_VARIABLE');
```

I think it should work with Laravel 5.1 as well as [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) is a PHP function.

Comment: That returns NULL. I would assume that the test is looking at the phpunit.xml file for environment variables.

Answer (score 4):

Start `Dotenv` to get .env variables in the TestCase stage

```
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
    $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();

    Dotenv::load(__DIR__.'/../');
    $this->baseUrl = env('APP_URL', $this->baseUrl);

    return $app;
}
```

Comment: Or `getenv` also OK for me.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that Christopher Raymonds suggestion above, **replacing** the

```
Dotenv::load call
```

**with**

```
this $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env.testing');
```

works with **Laravel 5.4**

**See Example:**

```
protected $baseUrl = 'http://localhost';

/**
 * Creates the application.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
 */

public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

    $app->loadEnvironmentFrom('.env');
    $this->baseUrl = env('APP_URL', $this->baseUrl);

    return $app;
}
```

Comment: This should be accepted as it's the only thing that worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my **.env** file:

`APP_URL=http://project.dev`

I then modified the **createApplication** function in **tests/TestCase.php**

```
/**
 * Creates the application.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
 */
public function createApplication()
{
    $this->baseUrl = env('APP_URL', $this->baseUrl);

    $app = require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel::class)->bootstrap();

    return $app;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that also returns NULL for me.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I needed to add the APP_URL key to my phpunit.xml file.

For whatever reason, I thought some .env file would also be loaded in the process but apparently that's not the case.

Comment: I needed to start `Dotenv` to get them in this stage

Answer (score 0):

I modified the createApplication function in tests/TestCase.php adding this lines after bootstrap ...->bootstrap();

```
$env = new Dotenv\Dotenv(dirname(__DIR__), '../.env'); 
$env->load();
```